# Using String[] args Parameter as Variable in .setQ Parameters (Google Drive API V3)

Tags: java, parameters, google-api, google-drive-api, mime-types

I'm trying to download .bin and .xml files from Google Drive using the API, so I created a parameter in the String[] args that defines the mime type.

The method requires specifying the mimetype in the .setQ, so I'm wondering if mimeType can be set to the parameter that defines whether its .bin or .xml.

```
private static void downloadFile(Drive service, String src_dir, String dst_dir, String mime_type) {
        try {
            FileList result = service.files().list()
                //application/x-binary for bin files; (application or text)/xml for xml files
                .setQ("'googledrivefolderid' in parents " + "and (mimeType = mime_type)")
                .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)")
                .execute();
            List<File> files = result.getFiles();
            if (files == null || files.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("No files found.");
            } else {
                //System.out.println("Files:");
                for (File file : files) {
                    String fileId = file.getId();
                    String fileName = file.getName();
                    OutputStream outputstream = new FileOutputStream(dst_dir + fileName);
                    service.files().get(fileId)
                    .executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputstream);
                    outputstream.flush();
                    outputstream.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the files with the mimeTypes of `.bin` or `.xml` in the specific folder using files.list method in Drive API v3.

  - The mimeTypes of the files of `.bin` or `.xml` are `application/x-binary` and `(application or text)/xml`, respectively.
- You want to achieve this using the search query.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Sample search query 1:

The search query for retrieving the files of `application/x-binary` or `application/xml` or `text/xml` in the specific folder of `googledrivefolderid` can be created as follows.

```
'googledrivefolderid' in parents and (mimeType = 'application/x-binary' or mimeType = 'application/xml' or mimeType = 'text/xml')
```

- If the mimeType of the files are different, you can check it using the method of Files: get in Drive API. You can test it at [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get). When you test it, please input the file ID and click "EXECUTE" button.

#### References:

- [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)
- [Search for files and folders](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Close. Is it possible to set mimeType = some variable? Or does it have to specifically defined? If for example I wanted to have the program download files from google drive of every possible format, I would have to have 'mimeType =' for every format type? Or can it be open-ended and comforms to the type I define in the method parameter: private static void downloadFile(Drive service, String src_dir, String dst_dir, String mime_type) {

Comment: @Phanotak Thank you for replying. When you want to retrieve the files with several specific mimeTypes, how about the following 2 patterns. 1. Use the search query like `mimeType = 'mimeType1' or mimeType = 'mimeType2' or mimeType = 'mimeType3' or ,,, `. And download each file. 2. At first, retrieve the file list of all files. And retrieve the files with the required mimeTypes from the list. Then, download each file. If the file list is retrieved every mimeType, the process cost will be high. So I proposed above 2 patterns. If those were not useful for your situation, I apologize.